# Inverse A Tree LeetCode

Tags: java, binary-tree

So I am working on a problem on LeetCode where I must invert a binary tree.

Problem:

[image: image of the problem]

and here's my solution:

```
class Solution {
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        TreeNode newTree = root;
        return invertTreeHelper(root, newTree);
    }

    public TreeNode invertTreeHelper(TreeNode root, TreeNode newTree)
    {
       if(root == null)
           return null; 
        
       newTree.val = root.val;         
       newTree.left = invertTreeHelper(root.right, newTree.left); 
       newTree.right = invertTreeHelper(root.left, newTree.right); 
       return newTree; 
    }
}
```

The given input is:

```
[4,2,7,1,3,6,9]
```

My expected output is:

```
[4,7,2,9,6,3,1]
```

However, my output is:

```
[4,7,7,9,6,6,9]
```

So clearly, my output does not work for the left side of the tree. I want to know where I went wrong. Is anyone please able to help me with this?

Comment: The problem you are facing is that you are replacing left with right and then replacing right with the new left(current right). Same problem as swapping `x` and `y` values without using a temp variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newTree = root` means that if you now change `newTree.left` you change `root.left` as well, you do not have an actual new tree, you just manipulate one tree in place. If you want to do that you must be careful not to overwrite stuff that you need later on. If you want to swap two numbers you cannot write `a=b; b=a;` since at the second assignment `a` would have already been changed. But you do just that with `left` and `right`.
Basically you should write:

```
public void invertTree(TreeNode node) {
   if (node == null)
       return; 
    TreeNode tmp = node.left;
    node.left = node.right
    node.right = tmp;
    invertTree(node.left);
    invertTree(node.right);
}
```

Alternatively you can actually create a new tree and then you do not need to worry about the `tmp` part but you would need quite a few `new TreeNode` statements at the right places, then you must not use a node in both the original and the new tree.

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I was under the impression that you couldn't do such a thing with a tree. Thank you so much! It's been fixed and the solution works.

Answer (score -1):

Heres my solution from leetcode. Its a simple recursion problem with a postorder traversal. Soln is 0(n) and it ranks top 1% in runtime and top 3% in memory on leetcode

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
 //recursion problem, swap every left with the right node in postorder 
class Solution {
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) return null;
        if(root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            return root;
        }
        invertTree(root.left);
        invertTree(root.right);
        TreeNode temp = root.left;
        root.left = root.right;
        root.right = temp;
        return root;
    }
}
```